# Error converting Raster to Spatial Points Dataframe in R

Tags: r, gis, raster, tiff

I am trying to convert a `.TIF` file to a spatial points data frame in R. My code was working but something seems to have changed and now I am getting the error:

```
Error in .availableRAM(maxmem) : object '_raster_availableRAM' not found
```

Here is my code block:

```
dem <- raster('../scratch/DEM.tif')

dempts <- as(dem, 'SpatialPointsDataFrame')
```

Comment: Looks like you've run out of memory. Difficult to say without the tif file and details of your environment. Does restarting R change anything? Failing that does a reboot make a difference?

Comment: Have tried restarting R and rebooting my computer with no avail. I tried the readGDAL function and it allowed me to import and convert to a spatial points data frame with no trouble. Seems like it may be an issue with the raster package.

Comment: The message suggests that "raster" was not installed properly. Can you provide some information about your system? Can you reinstall "raster" in a clean workspace ? Did you install it in a non-standard way?

Comment: Reinstalled the package and its working now. Thanks Robert.